# Next.js build and Docker Compose - injecting a config.json file

Tags: docker-compose, next.js13

I have a Next.js app that I want to deploy in different environments and I want to use a config.json file to set a series of variables that will determine the functionality of the app.

What I would like to do is use Docker Compose to set the config.json file that is to be used at runtime. My issue is that when I build the Next app in the Dockerfile, it uses the config.json file that is present at build time, and I cannot overwrite this file at runtime. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Realised the issue - my routes were static rather than dynamic (https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/server-components#server-rendering-strategies) so needed to add `export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic';` in `route.ts` to force them to get the injected `config.json` file.